# Popfax API Soap PHP

Tags: php, soap, popfax-api

Hi i am trying to use popfax api but i always receive e complex error

```
<?php
ini_set("soap.wsdl_cache_enabled", "0");
$username = 'email@gmail.com';  
$password = 'password';
$usernameToken = array('email' => $username,'password' => $password);
$wsse_ns = "http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2002/07/secext";
$SoapVarUser = new SoapVar($username, XSD_STRING, NULL, $wsse_ns, NULL, $wsse_ns);
$SoapVarPass = new SoapVar($password, XSD_STRING, NULL, $wsse_ns, NULL, $wsse_ns);
$wsse_auth = new SoapVar($usernameToken, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, NULL, $wsse_ns, 'AuthenticationHeader', $wsse_ns);
$header=new SoapVar($wsse_auth, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT, NULL, $wsse_ns, 'Security', $wsse_ns);
$wsse_header = new SoapHeader($wsse_ns, 'AuthenticationHeader', $header, true);
$wsdl = "https://api3.popfax.com/?service=Popfax&wsdl";
$client = new SoapClient($wsdl, array("trace" => 1));
$client->__setSoapHeaders(array($wsse_header));
$response = $client->__SoapCall('PopfaxService.getAccountInfo',array());
var_dump($response);
?>
```

But when i run this php code appear this error:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught SoapFault exception: [SOAP-ENV:Client] Error 107 in /home/diogopms/public_html/sapo/popfax.php:17
Stack trace:
#0 /home/diogopms/public_html/sapo/popfax.php(17): SoapClient->__soapCall('PopfaxService.g...', Array)
#1 {main}
  thrown in /home/diogopms/public_html/sapo/popfax.php on line 17
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The password sent to the server must be MD5 hashed. See the Popfax API documentation.

```
$password = md5('yourpassword');
```